# Why am I getting content type error when hosting blazor webassembly on s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, blazor

I uploaded a blazor webassembly project to an static website hosted aws s3 bucket and when accessing it from a browser i get this error:

[browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fseh7.png)

I figured that changing the content-type on the bucket of the file 'mono.wasm' to 'application/wasm' but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the content-type change had not gone through yet on CloudFront. A refresh on the associated CloudFront instance solved the problem.